# How should I run a webpage every ten minutes?

Tags: web-services, automation, scheduled-tasks

I am writing an ASP.NET web page which calls an API to update my client's property website using XML data. The data from the API is real-time, so I would like to run the page every 10 minutes.

Clearly I don't want to load my page manually to keep my client's property website up-to-date. There is a lot of help in Stack Overflow and elsewhere on this type of question but I have become a little overwhelmed by the options. I think that one way to go would be:

1. Windows Task Scheduler to fire every ten minutes (to trigger a VB.Net Service)
2. VB.Net Service (to run the web page)
3. My page runs..

That feels like overkill, and I haven't written a Windows Service or used the Task Scheduler and it feels like there should be 2 steps not three.

Now if I do use a VB.Net Service then I think that it might be better to give more work to the VB.Net Service rather than put my script in a web page, but I am used to writing web pages!

I can't help feeling that if I just keep the page open in a browser somewhere I can easily use JavaScript to run the page every 10 minutes, but that means ensuring it's open in a browser. Bad solution I think...

What I need is an overview of my options to make an informed decision and if it means learning then fine. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript/Jquery to call a page/webmethod continously in timely manner

```
setInterval(function() {
      // call your page or webmethod
}, 1000 * 60 * x); // x is your time interval in mins, in your case x=10
```

Comment: Thank you for you response, think I will be trying to write a service and do it that way.. Be nice not to have to have the page running..

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best approach would be to create a windows service and have the service call the web page. The windows service is much more stable than the Task Scheduler because the task scheduler can overlap if the previous Scheduled event did not finish. Also using the windows service gives you more control over error handling and logging

Get started with this link:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CSWindowsService-9f2f568e

Comment: Hi Victor, sounds good, I think I will also need to set the service up somewhere in windows so that it can be stopped and started... I think that where I said Task Scheduler, I should write "Windows Services to start my ASP.Net Service and keep it running"